# How to catch "Invalid hex digit"?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, exception

I have a program, in which a SQLException gets thrown:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: Invalid hex digit
```

The error gets thrown in `oracle.sql.RAW.hexString2Bytes`, because the input data is invalid.

How can I catch this specific error without catching all other SQLExceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by two method.

One is [`SQLException#getErrorCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode%28%29) which will return an `int`, vendor-specific exception code for the `SQLException` object, and compare the `int` ( I don't know the exception code for "Invalid hex digit", but may be you can get this with `System.out.println()` )

And other method is you can get exception message by [`Throwable#getMessage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage%28%29) and check the message string.

Further you can refer : [Retrieving Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html#retrieving_exceptions)

Comment: I think it's unlikely that the error code will be set, since it's not a database error but a driver error.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I don't have resources to test it now, but you can test it, remove database jar file and print error code, you will get the error code for class not found I think.

Comment: The error code is 17059. Is it really vendor specific? This would mean, that I have to rewrite the exception handling, if I switch the dbms.

Comment: @ceving Yes, for some other vendor error code may be different, but to not rewrite the code, you can set somewhere in your configuration file (properties) and retrieve from there, so in future, incase you change your database vendor, you don't need to play with existing code. Just update properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can process your Exception, check the condition if you want to handle or not. If not handled, you can **throw the original Exception** to outer catch blocks to process.

```
try {
    ... your code here ...
} catch (SqlException e) {
    if (e.getErrorCode() == ...) {
        ... do your exception handling
    } else {
        throw e;  // <-- re-throw the original Exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. Exceptions are caught in Java based on their type (`SQLException` in this case). But still, you can catch all `SQLException` objects, inspect the exception message, and thhen process only those exceptions you are interested in (those with the specified message).